# How do I open under VNC a Firefox window that belongs to a Firefox session running outside of VNC?

Tags: firefox, vnc, session

How do I open under VNC a Firefox window that belongs to a Firefox session running outside of VNC?

It would be some converse of <del>`--new-instance: open new instance, not a new window in running instance`</del>. Some explicit "force-remote" (`--remote`) flag does not exist (and anyway would easily suggest opening a new window outside of VNC (even though the command is issued under VNC)) and `--new-window` doesn't do the job.

**Update.** Running `env DISPLAY=:1 firefox --new-window` with VNC listening on 5901/6001 returns the infamous `Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window, you must first close the existing Firefox process, or restart your system.`

Comment: By "running outside of VNC", do you mean that you have two X sessions running - one on a physical display and another for VNC?

Comment: @Hitechcomputergeek Yes. But now I became a little uncertain: what else could I have meant?

Comment: I see what you mean. Everything on the same box. No other computer involved.

Comment: Dunno, but I usually use VNC by sharing the same X display as the physical screen, rather than a second display just for VNC.

Comment: I don't think Firefox supports, or any common GUI application, supports this.

Comment: @muru Your answer looks promising (as/of an explanation), so if you can add a justification, please turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try either `firefox --display=:0` or `DISPLAY=:0 firefox`. This should theoretically work over SSH as well as over a second VNC display. However, I have not tested this solution.

Comment: You mean the other way around, `env DISPLAY=:1 firefox`, assuming VNC listening on 5901/6001, but *this* is where I get `Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window, you must first close the existing Firefox process, or restart your system.` (And let's try @Hitechcomputergeek again. The @nickname isn't shown at the beginning.)

Comment: Usually the physical display would be `:0` and VNC would be `:1`. By convention, ports 5901/6001 would mean VNC is using display `:1`. However, you can actually use any port, and in your case it may well be different. You can list the running X processes with `ps -fC Xorg`.

Comment: I know. I was talking about something else.